# force:createRecord is not working properly in Winter 18

Tags: winter18

force:createrecord is not working properly in winter 18.

I have **overriden** **"New" button of opportunity** with custom lightning component. 
for opportunity creation, I have used force:createRecord at various places in other lightning components. 
**Issue is, whenever this event fire it open the "New" button overriden component.**

Answer (score 1):

This is a winter 18 known issue. Check [this](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EFOoQAO&title=when-attempting-to-create-a-new-record-after-firing-the-force-createrecord-event-the-page-will-go-in-a-loop) link for more. Fixed in most of the data centers and release is in progress.